# Generate model fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When attempting to follow examples from *Engineering Long-Lasting Software* (Fox and Patterson) the command:

```
rails generate model Moviegoer name:string provider:string uid:string
```

run from `~/Documents/application_root` (a project home directory generated by course staff) results in a

```
rails generate model Moviegoer name:string provider:string uid:string:command not found
```

message being displayed; why might such a message be returned and what can be done to make the command execute successfully?

Comment: Check to see that the `rails` is command is recognized. What happens when you only type `rails`?

Comment: The 'rails' command works just fine as the other examples have not caused an issue. 

"mu is too short" - the command is being run without quotes... though the same isn't really of question as blockquotes are standard practice for citing commands, etc.; perhaps what you meant to say was not understood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I tried again and only changed the input by copying/pasting a space character from the portion of the command which was working ('rails model generate' became 'rails model generate Moviegoer' with the last space being reused) and the command worked. Since the original commands from which this command was derived were typed into a terminal from one input source the mystery of how the console could have seen two different space characters remains...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'sudo' at the beginning if you haven't already.
If rails installed to default root location, then your command will only find your app folder when ran as root user.

Comment: The user in question has sufficient privileges AFAIK but trying again anyway as 'root' didn't work. Also (oddly) the command 'rails model generate' seems to work as the message indicating the command format and command options is displayed when it is entered... unfortunately any additional parameters (like a model name or even options like '-f' & '-p') don't help the matter as the same error is returned.